# Why does the message "The Critical Analyzer detected slow paths on the broker" mean in Artemis broker?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Setup: I have an artemis broker HA cluster with 3 brokers. The replication policy is replication. Each broker is running in its own VM.

Problem: When I leave my brokers running for long time, usually after 5-6 hours, I get the below error.

> 2022-11-21 21:32:37,902 WARN
> [org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalMeasure] Component
> org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager
> is expired on path 0 2022-11-21 21:32:37,902 INFO
> [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224107: The Critical
> Analyzer detected slow paths on the broker.  It is recommended that
> you enable trace logs on org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical
> while you troubleshoot this issue. You should disable the trace logs
> when you have finished troubleshooting. 2022-11-21 21:32:37,902 ERROR
> [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224079: The process for
> the virtual machine will be killed, as component
> org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager@46d59067
> is not responsive 2022-11-21 21:32:37,969 WARN
> [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222199: Thread dump:
> ******************************************************************************* Complete Thread dump "Thread-517
> (ActiveMQ-IO-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$7@437da279)"
> Id=602 TIMED_WAITING on
> java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@75f49105
> at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
> -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@75f49105
> at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
> at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
> at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
> at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

What does this really mean? I understand that the critical analyzer sees an error and it halts the broker but what is causing this error?

Comment: What ActiveMQ Artemis version are you using, I see some fix related to the critical analyzer in the last versions? https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20ARTEMIS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22critical%20analyzer%22%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC

Comment: Apache Artemis 2.18.0 and the VMs are running AlmaLinux 8.6

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/critical-analysis.html). Basically you are experiencing some issue tat the broker detects and it shuts down before it becomes too irresponsive. Setting the policy to LOG you might get more clues on the issue.

Comment: I have changed the policy to TRACE but unable to replicate the scenario. The brokers have been running for 24h now.